# Convert a simple if/else into an expression?

Tags: logic

I need to map a 2-bit number from one definition to another (the numbers below represent bits):

```
00 -> 00
01 -> 10
10 -> 11
11 -> 01
```

This can be done by a simple `if/else` block in C/C++, e.g.,

```
if (n != 0) {
  if (n > 2) n = 1;
  else n += 1;
}
```

My question: is it possible to convert the code block into one expression (using arithmetic and/or logic operations)? why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note that based on your code sample, I'll be assuming a C-like language here that has bitwise operations -- most languages have such operators, anyway. If your language is not C or doesn't use these specific operators, update your question with a specific language.)

Sure, this is definitely possible. Based on this, we can tell that the LSB of output is equivalent to the MSB of the input, so this bit is easy enough to compute with a right-shift (and isolation of the LSB for safety if the input is greater than 3):

```
(n >> 1) & 1
```

The MSB of the output can be expressed as binary XOR of the two input bits. So we'll XOR `n` with itself shifted left one bit, then isolate the second bit.

```
(n ^ (n << 1)) & 2
```

Then we combine this with the first expression using binary OR:

```
((n ^ (n << 1)) & 2) | ((n >> 1) & 1)
```

([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc1b67cf2adde2eb) in C++.)

---

You may be asking which is better. The answer, I think is that your code sample is much better for maintenance, as the expression I've written is extremely opaque and will take some deciphering even if you understand what the bitwise operators do. Your code is less likely to be a problem for others who have to maintain this program.

If high performance is absolutely critical (hint: it's probably not) then my code will perform faster. On clang 4.0.0 with full optimization, my code not only compiles to fewer instructions, but (much more importantly) has no branches or conditional operations; your code has two such instructions. Your code will perform faster when `n==0` and approximately the same when `n!=0`, assuming that the CPU correctly predicts the branch. However, it will perform worse if the CPU mispredicts a branch in either case.

The tl;dr is that my code will perform better *more consistently*, even if yours might perform better in some cases (`n==0` and correctly-predicted branch).

Comment: Great answer, also appreciate the performance analysis, thanks! BTW, it seems that your solution is based on the clever observation of the current problem... a broader question would be, is there a generic converting method for a list of many elements (instead of 4) with longer bits (instead of 2)?

Comment: @bruin A generic method would be to use a map structure (such as `std::map<int, int>` in C++).

Comment: I was not clear in my last question. I mean, is there a generic/systematic method to convert this kind of number mapping (n-bits to n-bits or to m-bits, for example) into arithmetic/logic expressions? just for curiosity :)

Comment: @bruin Ah, I understand. One potential approach would be to make a [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) for each output bit. This may not always generate an ideal expression, but it will always generate at least one of the many possible expressions that uses no conditional instructions. Note that this approach will be rather cumbersome the more input bits you have.